# Flex AS3 - About variable instances, event listeners and garbage collection

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

QUESTION ONE:

In the following example, ive added a listener to the foundMic. My question is if i re-run the foobar.initMic(); to reinitialize the microphone will i end up with a dead event listener floating in memory, and would it be picked up by garbage collection? Does calling the .getMicrophone() just reattach the same resource to foundMic or does it destroy the old foundMic and create a new instance of foundMic in memory.

As in if its the exact same foundMic then adding the event listener will silently fail and not create a second listener. But if foundMic becomes a new instance then it would be creating a new listener. Then back to the question about garbage collection, would it be considered unreferenced for clean up?

```
public class foobar {

    public static var foundMic:Microphone = null;

    public static function initMic():void {
        foundMic = Microphone.getMicrophone();
        foundMic.codec = SoundCodec.SPEEX;
        foundMic.setSilenceLevel(0, 5000);
        foundMic.gain = 50;
        foundMic.setUseEchoSuppression(true);
        foundMic.soundTransform.volume = 1;
        foundMic.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, onMicStatusEvent);
        return;
     }

    public static function onMicStatusEvent(event:StatusEvent):void {
        if (foundMic && !foundMic.muted) someButton.enabled = true;
        else someButton.enabled = false;
        return;
    }

} // END CLASS
```

QUESTION TWO:

Based on question one, if i added a remove listener just before adding the listener, does that actually remove the listener on the second time ran which was created when the method was ran the first time? Or is that foundMic already a new instance from the .getMicrophone() so nothing is removed because the first listener is already floating in memory associated with the previous instance of foundMic?

```
    public static function initMic():void {
        foundMic = Microphone.getMicrophone();
        .
        .
        .
        foundMic.removeEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, onMicStatusEvent);
        foundMic.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, onMicStatusEvent);
        return;
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

foundMic will just be assigned a new value which is a reference to to the Microphone - nothing should be garbage collected.

A case where the garbage collector should kick in is something like this:

```
var someVar:Sprite;
for(var i:int = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    someVar = new Sprite();
}
```

In this case you've created 5 new Sprite objects but ended up with only one assigned to the someVar variable - the other 4 should get garbage collected at some point because they are not referenced by any variable.

As far as question two, the code you have should give you an error the first time you call initMic() since at that point there is no onMicStatusEvent listener yet. Before trying to remove the event listener first test to see if it exists:

```
if(foundMic.hasEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS)
{
    foundMic.removeEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, onMicStatusEvent);
}
foundMic.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, onMicStatusEvent);
```

This code will always remove the event listener first if it exist and then subsequently add a new event listener. However, in this case I don't see any reason for this, as addEventListener by itself should work just fine - multiple calls are all on the same object, so no matter how many times you call initMic() you should only have one event listener running - there's no need to manually remove the listener and then recreate.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense, looks like the first section of code is all i need, Thanks. On your comment about an error on the remove, it doesn't error (tested). Adobe docs state its a silent fail, no harm no foul.

Comment: I don't think you get errors when removing event listeners that haven't been added. If you did, I'd have all kinds of errors in my code all the time. Plus, functions are not procedural.  Just because it occurrs in the Class body below the other function doesn't mean it doesn't "exist" yet. Sorry, have to downvote this because there is so much technically inaccurate information in this answer.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship I meant that foundMic would not yet have the event listener attached, poorly phrased perhaps, but I don't think wrong. But I agree that I was wrong about removing event listeners when they haven't been added.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what happens with event listeners. `someObject.addEventListener('someEvent', someFunction)` hands `someObject` a reference to `someFunction`. Because of the way scope works in ActionScript, the function will have access to everything in the scope of the code that created it. So until you call `removeEventListener`, the instance where the function exists will be held in memory as long as `someObject` is in memory.

**However,** in your case, there *is* no instance, because by using static functions your listeners will exist from the time your Class `FooBar` is first referenced until your swf is taken out of the computer's memory.

There is no net effect of removing the listener prior to adding it, because it is exactly the same function being handed to exactly the same object, which isn't going to call your function twice.

For more on how event listeners work in detail, [check out this blog post](http://www.developria.com/2010/08/rethinking-addeventlistener-an.html).